# C# keypress writes in field instead

Tags: c#, combobox, textfield, keypress, keydown

I'm writing an windows form application where I need to set a boolean true whenever a key is pressed.

Simple enough, however since I have a textfield and some comboboxes whenever I try to press the key it just writes whatever key I press in the textfield/comboboxes.
It does not matter if I click somewhere else in the application.

I tried making an project without textfields and comboboxes and it works perfectly.

How can i have both input fields and keypress events in the same form?

Answer (score 2):

Set the [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property so that all keystroke events will be channeled to the form's event handlers.  Once execution hits your event handlers, you can set whatever variables you need, including setting a Boolean for each keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial for this here [How to: Handle Keyboard Input at the Form Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Windows Forms provides the ability to handle keyboard messages at the
>   form level, before the messages reach a control.
>
> To handle a keyboard message at the form level.
>
> **Handle the KeyPress or KeyDown event of the startup form, and set the
>   KeyPreview property of the form to true** so that keyboard messages are
>   received by the form before they reach any controls on the form.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyPress +=
            new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress);
    }

    // Detect all numeric characters at the form level and consume 1, 
    // 4, and 7. Note that Form.KeyPreview must be set to true for this
    // event handler to be called.
    void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
                e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' pressed.");

            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                case (char)49:
                case (char)52:
                case (char)55:
                    MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
                        e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' consumed.");
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```